# MaxUploadSizeExceededException handled but file is STILL uploaded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

So I'm using Spring Webflow to upload a file and the `CommonsMultipartResolver` with a max file size param.

When the max file size is exceed the `CommonsMultipartResolver` throws a `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` which I'm catching and handling just fine by returning to my original view with a new ModelAndView with an error message added to the model.

Problem is, the browser STILL goes through the process of uploading the file anyway?? Is there any way to stop this? I don't really want my users to spend their time uploading 10 or 20 meg files only to be told the max limit is 5 meg (or some similar example)...

Comment: Looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FILEUPLOAD-145 Though updating to commons-fileupload-1.3 did not solve the issue for me!

Comment: I am facing the same issue! Any thing work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you have to close the incoming request input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Can you first check the `request.getContentLength()` or `request.getHeaders("Content-Length")`? Like in a Filter or Interceptor if necessary.

( [How to know the file size when uploading via multipart form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920689/how-to-know-the-file-size-when-uploading-via-multipart-form-data) )