# How to get the real file size of a file in a multipart/form-data request

Tags: file-upload, http-headers, multipartform-data

As the title says, I need to get the real filesize of a file posted as a `multipart/form-data` request.

I'm based in the JSF world but I think the problem is technology-agnostic (only depends on HTTP).

The value specified in the *Content-Length* header is not sufficient because it includes the boundaries and other form parameters.

Example request (body only):

```
-----------------------------355432893771247592819421210
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="composeform"

composeform
-----------------------------355432893771247592819421210

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="javax.faces.ViewState"

-9107117821100047188:3613431652649065231
-----------------------------355432893771247592819421210
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="3byte.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

abc

-----------------------------355432893771247592819421210--
```

The last part of the request body contains the file, in this case a file named "3byte.txt" containing the characters "abc".

As you can see, the filesize is not included in the request, therefore the only way I see to get the value, is to calculate it based on the *Content-Length* header and the size of the boundaries and other form parameters.

**Additional requirements:**

- the solution shouldn't have to read/parse the whole request to get the filesize (this would obviously be easy)
- there may be more form parameters in the request, before or/and after the part which contains the file (in contrast to my example)

**Similar questions not solving the problem:**

- [How to know the file size when uploading via multipart form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920689/how-to-know-the-file-size-when-uploading-via-multipart-form-data)
- [Get file size from multipart form upload Content-Length header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300641/get-file-size-from-multipart-form-upload-content-length-header)
- [Calculate size multipart/form-data encoded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035893/calculate-size-multipart-form-data-encoded-file)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. You cannot expect that the Content-Length header is set for the `multipart` message (some multipart request types even forbid a content length header). It's only required that *either* a `Content-Length` header *or* a `Transfer-Encoding` header is present.
2. There must be no `Content-Length` header in a part of a multipart message.

However, your sender *may* set an additional parameter in the disposition header. You could leverage this to set the file size as follows:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="3byte.txt"; size=123
```

But this would be purely optional, the parameters's name would be arbitrary, and no sender is required to include this parameter. That means, a HTTP server engine can never rely on it.

Comment: It looks like there really is no standard solution for this, therefore I'll accept this answer now.